# Insert images (NSData) into BLOB fields

Tags: php, mysql, ios, blob

From iOS app to php script, I want to store a bench of images as BLOB types:

```
 $profile_images = $_REQUEST['profile_images_array'];//get the array of images

        //loop the images and store them one by one
        foreach($profile_images as $image){ 
        $sqlinsertimages = "insert into profile_images (id_client,image) Values ('".$id."',mysql_real_escape_string('".$image."'))";
        $result = mysql_query($sqlinsertimages);

        }
```

The insert would work fine if I eliminate the image field (which is BLOB type), so the issue is obviously with the saving BLOB types in the table.

How to store properly the images in PHP as BLOB?

PS: not willing to adopt the file system storage.

Comment: what problem do you encounter? make sure your table meets data type storage requirements: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/storage-requirements.html#idm47627770414160

Comment: Hi, yes the image field is BLOB type, indeed I am using MySQL

Comment: It is BLOB but, what type of BLOB? You cannot store data bigger than 64KB in a BLOB type field. Are you sure your table meets the requirements? And again, what problem do you encounter exactly? Any error messages?

Comment: I changed the BLOB type to `longblob`, for the error messages, where exactly should I see? which file, I am using MAMP. Thanx.

Comment: change to $result = mysql_query($sqlinsertimages) OR die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess that work finally, didn't knew that I had to save the image to the server before saving it to MySQL:

```
            foreach($profile_images as $image){ 
                //Get the file as a string before inserting it to table
                $content = file_get_contents($image);
                $content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
                $sqlinsertimages = "insert into profile_images (id_client,image) Values ('".$id."','".$content."')";

                $result = mysql_query($sqlinsertimages);
            }
```